# append a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table that display data whenever a user clicks the start event button,but i need to know how to append the records when the user clicks the start button again,the previous record gets overridden

here is my javascript code

```
function DisplayData(downTime) {
        console.log(downTime);
        var newContent = '';
        $.each(downTime.data, function (i, item) {
            newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.downTime);     
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CategoryName);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.StartTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.EndTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Comments);
            newContent  = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);
        });
        $('#DowntimeList').html(newContent);
 }
```

and here is my html code:

```
<table id="Downtimetable" class="hesto">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>End Of DownTime</th>                   
                     <th>Category Name</th>
                     <th>Start Time</th>
                     <th>End Time</th>
                     <th>Comments</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="DowntimeList">

             </tbody>
             <tfoot>
             </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: I would suggest using a data binding library such as knockout as well. because this would then product nice looking HTML and javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `append()` instead of overwriting the `html()`:

```
$('#DowntimeList').append(newContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in the title of your question, [**`append()`**](https://api.jquery.com/append/) it.

```
$('#DowntimeList').html(newContent);
```

Should be

```
$('#DowntimeList').append(newContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use,

```
 document.getElementById('DowntimeList').InnerHtml = document.getElementById('DowntimeList').InnerHtml+newContent
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what OP currently has, and will overwrite the content for each new row he adds.